# Laravel many to many relation: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a many to many relation:

```
table 1 books  
table 2 authors  
table 3 books_authors  
        book_id, author_id
```

The problem is when insert a new record, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'book_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `books_authors_relationship` (`author_id`, `book_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (3, , 2015-12-10 17:17:28, 2015-12-10 17:17:28))

**Author model**

```
class Author extends Model
{
   public function Book(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book','books_authors_relationship','book_id','author_id')->withTimestamps();
   }
}
```

**Book model**

```
   class Book extends Model
    {
    public function section(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section','id');
    }

        public function author(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author','books_authors_relationship','book_id','author_id')->withTimestamps();
        }
    }
```

**Book Controller**

```
 public function create($id)
        {
            $authors = Author::lists('first_name','id');
            $section_id = Section::find($id);
            return view('books.create_book',compact('section_id','authors'));

        }
     public function store(storeBookRequest $request)
        {
           // dd($request->input('authors'));
            $book_title = $request ->input('book_title');
            $book_edition = $request ->input('book_edition');
            $date_publication = $request ->input('date_publication');
            $book_isbn = $request ->input('book_isbn');
            $book_description = $request ->input('book_description');
            $file = $request ->file('image');
            $destinationPath = 'images';
            $filename = $file ->getClientOriginalName();
            $file ->move($destinationPath,$filename);
            //join to author
            $authorsIds = $request ->input('authors');


            $section_id = $request -> section_id;


            $new_book = new Book;
            $new_book ->book_title = $book_title;
            $new_book ->book_edition = $book_edition;
            $new_book ->date_publication = $date_publication;
            $new_book ->book_isbn = $book_isbn;
            $new_book ->book_description = $book_description;
            $new_book ->image_name = $filename;

            $new_book ->section_id = $section_id;


            $new_book->author()->attach($authorsIds);

            $new_book ->save();
          return redirect('admin_section');

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to save the `$new_book` before you can attach authors. This is because the new book doesn't have a primary key. The primary key is set when the record actually exists inside the database.

Your code:

```
$new_book ->section_id = $section_id;

$new_book->author()->attach($authorsIds);

$new_book->save();
```

Should be:

```
$new_book ->section_id = $section_id;

if ($new_book->save()) {
    $new_book->author()->attach($authorsIds);
}
```